# what is billing account in cloud based/subscription based services?

Tags: billing, google-cloud-billing

Hello everyone i would just like to know the concept of billing account(s) often associated in cloud billing or subscription based services. how does this work and how are the account balances calculated and updated for any particular user? i mean does the balance in this account shows how much i have to pay to a services provider and further more is this account balance updated as soon as i consume a service or is it calculated on a certain date(billing cycle date) using the usage event captured? Thanks in advance couldn't find the appropriate tags for question so pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

A cloud billing account is paying for services delivered on projects hosted on the platform and associated with that account.. I'm assuming this is for Google since you tagged it as such.

This is different to the users on the platform.

It should show how much is consumed (CPU, ram, storage, etc) - in arrears. I'm pretty sure its live, so you could sit and watch it if you had nothing better to do :)